# how to access files stored in folder with its name fetched from database.(laravel)

Tags: laravel, file, file-upload, file-access

i have upload section that stores files name in user's table, and files in Folder named as File.
i want to access that file from name stored in database.
i.e if it is a zip file it should get downloaded, if doc, pdf etc it should get open online.

my code in **controller** that fetches files:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->select('attachments')->where('id',$id)->first();
$attach = explode(",", $users->attachments);
return View::make('admin.RegisterStaff.show')
            ->with('attach', $attach);
```

my code in blade file to display files:

```
<div class="col-md-4">   
 @foreach($attach as $data)
   <a href="public/files/{{$data}}" download="{{$data}}">{{ $data }}</a><br>
 @endforeach 
</div>
```

what is the best way to access files..??

Comment: u can try url() and use it in a href with download tag

Comment: @Jigs1212 i have changed my code but onclick of it i'm getting NotFoundHttpException

Comment: are ur files stored in public folder ?

Comment: yes in public/files

Comment: check the url which u are passing is correct ?? 

show us the url and may be the filestructure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
@if($data->getClientOriginalExtension() == 'docx')
    //do anything you want
@endif
```